# why onMapready is executing before executing the called task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a code in which i call function(getData) before map fragment so that function  is executed from that i call showList function but this is executed only after the OnMapready function. I actually don't know the reason behind it. The system first said that more work is done in main thread so skipped 49 frames to clear this i executed Showlist even as async task but the map function is called before ShowList(). Anyone say me the reason behind it. I know some logic is there but don't know what it is? 
my code

```
public class GetCo extends FragmentActivity implements     OnMapReadyCallback {
   String path1la, path1lo, path2la, path2lo;
   double dsla, dslo, ddla, ddlo, dp1la, dp1lo, dp2la, dp2lo;
   private GoogleMap mMap;

public String myJSON;
private static final String TAG_RESULT = "RESULT";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Taskname";
private static final String TAG_KILOMETER = "Kilometer";
private static final String TAG_TIMING = "Timing";
private static final String TAG_SOLA = "SourceLa";
private static final String TAG_SOLO = "SourceLo";
private static final String TAG_DLA = "DestinationLa";
private static final String TAG_DLO = "DestinationLo";
private static final String TAG_P1LA = "Path1La";
private static final String TAG_P1LO = "Path1Lo";
private static final String TAG_P2LA = "Path2La";
private static final String TAG_P2LO = "Path2Lo";
JSONArray array = null;

String id, name, kmeter, time, sla, slo, p1la, p1lo, p2la, p2lo, dla, dlo;
TableLayout tl;
TableRow tr;
int c, vt;
TextView tn, kms, tm;
Button map;
String result=null;
String task;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent in = getIntent();
    task = in.getExtras().getString("task");


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    getData();
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
 }


public void getData() {

    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http")
                    .authority("www.futuroitsolutions.in")
                    .appendPath("php_android_api")
                    .appendPath("datare.php")
                    .appendQueryParameter("Taskname", task);

            String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
            Log.d("String",task);
          Log.d("url",myUrl);
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(myUrl);

            // Depends on your web service
            httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Oops
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception squish) {
                }
            }


            return result;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            myJSON=result;
            Log.d("jsooon",myJSON);
            ShowList(myJSON);

        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();

}
public void ShowList(String json) {
final String vi = json;
{
    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                JSONObject j = null;


                j = new JSONObject(vi);
                //     String notes = j.getString("result");
                array = j.getJSONArray("result");


                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    kmeter = c.getString(TAG_KILOMETER);
                    time = c.getString(TAG_TIMING);
                    sla = c.getString(TAG_SOLA);
                    slo = c.getString(TAG_SOLO);
                    p1la = c.getString(TAG_P1LA);
                    p1lo = c.getString(TAG_P1LO);
                    p2la = c.getString(TAG_P2LA);
                    p2lo = c.getString(TAG_P2LO);
                    dla = c.getString(TAG_DLA);
                    dlo = c.getString(TAG_DLO);
                    vt = array.length();
                    String v = String.valueOf(c);
                    String x = String.valueOf(vt);
                    Log.d("tagggggg", v);
                    Log.d("tag", name);
                    Log.d("tag", kmeter);
                    Log.d("tag", time);
                    Log.d("tag", x);
                    Log.d("lat", sla);
                    Log.d("log", slo);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {



        }
    }
    GetData g = new GetData();
    g.execute();

}
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d("start","first");
    mMap = googleMap;
    //   dsla = Double.parseDouble(sla);
    try {
       // sla = URLEncoder.encode(sla, "UTF-8");
        Log.d("inmap", sla);
        dsla = Double.parseDouble(sla);
      //  slo = URLEncoder.encode(slo, "UTF-8");
        dslo = Double.parseDouble(slo);
        //path1la = URLEncoder.encode(path1la, "UTF-8");
        dp1la = Double.parseDouble(path1la);
       // path1lo = URLEncoder.encode(path1lo, "UTF-8");
        dp1lo = Double.parseDouble(path1lo);
       // path2la = URLEncoder.encode(path2la, "UTF-8");
        dp2la = Double.parseDouble(path2la);
       // path2lo = URLEncoder.encode(path2lo, "UTF-8");
        dp2lo = Double.parseDouble(path2lo);
      //  dla = URLEncoder.encode(dla, "UTF-8");
        ddla = Double.parseDouble(dla);
       // dlo = URLEncoder.encode(dlo, "UTF-8");
        ddlo = Double.parseDouble(dlo);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    String url1 = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(dsla,dslo,dp1la,dp1lo,ddla,ddlo);

    new connectAsyncTask(url1).execute();


    // Getting JSON from URL


    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng kakkanad = new LatLng(10.007243, 76.354628);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(kakkanad, 18));
    // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    //  .position(kakkanad)
    //  .title("Marker in kakkanad"));


    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Source, 18));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}


public String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl(double dsla,double dslo,double dp1la,double dp2lo,double ddla,double ddlo) {
    //Log.d("in func",sla);
    String c=String.valueOf(dsla);
    Log.d("in func",c);
    final LatLng source = new LatLng(dsla, dslo);
    final LatLng path1 = new LatLng(dp1la, dp2lo);
    final LatLng path2 = new LatLng(dp2la, dp2lo);
    final LatLng dest = new LatLng(ddla, ddlo);

    String origin = "", waypoints = "", destination = "";
    try {
        origin = "origin=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(source.latitude), "UTF-8") + "," + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(source.longitude), "UTF-8");
        waypoints = "waypoints=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(path1.latitude), "UTF-8") + "," + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(path1.longitude), "UTF-8");
        destination = "destination=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(dest.latitude), "UTF-8") + "," + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(dest.longitude), "UTF-8");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    }
    String way = "", sour = "", desty = "";
    try {
        way = URLEncoder.encode(waypoints, "UTF-8");
        desty = URLEncoder.encode(destination, "UTF-8");
        sour = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    }
    String key = "key=AIzaSyDOidVs6_dHl0cjEJ0-OhMfUY0oNFf1SOE";

    String params = origin + "&" + destination + "&" + waypoints + "&" + key;
    String output = "json";
    //   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
    // String url1="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=edapally,kerala&destination=ernakulam,kerala&waypoints=optimize:true|palarivattom,kerala|vytilla,kerala&key=AIzaSyDOidVs6_dHl0cjEJ0-OhMfUY0oNFf1SOE";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
            + output + "?" + params;
    Log.d("taqg", url);
    return url;
}

public void drawPath(String result) {
    if (result != null) {
        mMap.clear();
    }
    int height = 100;
    int width = 100;
    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.source);
    Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
    Bitmap ssource = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);

    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.way);
    Bitmap b1 = bitmapdraw1.getBitmap();
    Bitmap sway = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
            b1, width, height, false);


    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dest);
    Bitmap b2 = bitmapdraw2.getBitmap();
    Bitmap sdest = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b2, width, height, false);


    LatLng Source = new LatLng(dsla, dslo);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Source)
            .title("Source")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ssource)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Source, 18));
    LatLng path1 = new LatLng(dp1la, dp1lo);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(path1)
            .title("path")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(sway)));
    LatLng path2 = new LatLng(dp2la, dp2lo);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(path2)
            .title("path")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(sway)));
    LatLng dest = new LatLng(ddla, ddlo);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(dest)
            .title("Destination")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(sdest)));
    try {
        // Tranform the string into a json object
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        Log.d("array", result);
        JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
        int i = routeArray.length();
        String x = String.valueOf(i);
        Log.d("length", x);
        JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes
                .getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
        Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(list)
                .width(12)
                .color(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))//Google maps blue color
                .geodesic(true)
        );
     /*   for (int z = 0; z < list.size() - 1; z++) {
            LatLng src = list.get(z);
            LatLng desti = list.get(z + 1);
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(path1.latitude,path1.longitude),
                            new LatLng(path2.latitude,path2.longitude),
                            new LatLng(desti.latitude, desti.longitude))
                    .width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true));
        }
    */
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}

private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String url;

    connectAsyncTask(String urlPass) {
        url = urlPass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetCo.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        Log.d("jsonnnnnnnnnnnnnnn", json);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.hide();
        if (result != null) {
            Log.d("jsonppp", result);
            drawPath(result);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where have you forced the map to load after your Async task.

Comment: The code is asynchronous, so the method execution order is not guaranteed

Comment: Please make a [mcve] with an **[edit]**

Comment: that is what i dont know how to force the map to load after my asun task